# Convert float to int, when overflow range of int, make it max int or min int

Tags: c++, sse, typeconverter

I want to find a method that converting `float` to `int`, when overflow range of `int`, make it max `int` or min `int`.

Now I have a method like this

```
float x, mul = 1e5; 
int y; 

if (x * mul > (float)max_int_value)
    y = max_int_value;
else if (x * mul < (float)min_int_value)
    y = min_int_value;
else
    y = (int)x * mul;
```

but I think this is very slow(need two compare), and I want to use SSE to speed up when convert many values.

I want to get a more quick method, thank you very much.

Comment: After using which benchmarking tool did you conclude that this is "very slow"?

Comment: i use this convert to many numbers, and i want to find a more quick method may complete my demand in one step.

Comment: You say that you "think this is very slow," but do you **know** this is very slow?  If not, then you're not ready to start making changes to "improve performance."  Optimization is expensive.  Profile your program and find out where the performance hot spots are, then start improving performance using real data.

Comment: btw, In your example you cast x then multiply, so for x = 1.5 answer is 100000

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: How many is "many"?

Comment: sorry for unclear, i want to convert 1,000,000 numbers. and x * mul will compare to (float)max_int_value. i have optimize other code, and now maybe this is only code should be optimized, it use extra compare, i want to find a method to complete in one step

Comment: What is slow will be formatting and displaying the numbers or saving them to disk.  How do you know where the perceived slowness is?

Comment: You could use `minss` and `maxss` to make a branchless version, and hopefully you can use the `p`-versions and do 4 at once.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code that computes a vector with 4 floats.
you must include "emmintrin.h" at the beginning

```
float x[4]; // input vector
float y[4]; // result vector

__m128 mMaxInt = _mm_set1_ps((float)max_int_value);
__m128 mMinInt = _mm_set1_ps((float)min_int_value);
__m128 mMul = _mm_set1_ps(1e5);
__m128 mX = _mm_loadu_ps(x);
__m128 mY;

mY = _mm_mul_ps(mX, mMul);
mY = _mm_max_ps(mMinInt, mY);
mY = _mm_min_ps(mMaxInt, mY);

_mm_store_ps(y, mY);
```